# How can I find a log of calls message a specific extension in Asterisk?

Tags: asterisk

Question says it all. Trying to view a log of calls to/from an extension using Asterisk.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 11):

You can find the call detail record logs by inspecting the files `/etc/asterisk/cdr.conf` and `/etc/asterisk/cdr_custom.conf` (and any local files which they include) to determine where the log files are, or whether they're enabled. You can then view the call detail records.

By default, the records will be at `/var/log/asterisk/cdr-csv/Master.csv`. The above files will contain hints of any changes made locally to the logging configuration.

Comment: Weird my Master.csv is empty